# Selecting aesthetically pleasing random colors

Tags: c#, .net, colors

I have set of categories (the number of which changes according to specific state) each of which I need to assign a unique color.

I have tried using random colors but they look bad, so I need a method of generating random colors which suit each other.

Comment: I assume you're asking us to figure out how that random method would work? I can tell you now that it definitely won't be *random*. Do you have a particular algorithm in mind about how the code should know if two colors are "strange" or "funny"?

Comment: i need for example the two different colors ,suits (the first one suit the second) i donot know how to explain more , as my English not very good.. for example i need a specific color and all possible unique degree of the same color to look good and each category color suits the others colors.

Comment: Check out this site for an idea: http://colorschemedesigner.com/ - essentially, it generates a color, two lighter/darker colors, and then some colors that would go with it. I'm not sure what calculations it uses, but the idea is sound.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look in to colour theory and complementary colours; this will give you colours which work well together.

Have a look at [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/). Use the tetrad mode to see how you can combine 4 colours and different shades to give a number of distinct areas in the image.

Here is a [colour shades chart](http://www.december.com/html/spec/colorshades.html) and [some examples](http://www.december.com/html/spec/colorshadesuse.html) which may help you.

Comment: yeah this looks so great, but how to create or use the method they use to make this .

Comment: You would need a data structure to hold the colours and their complements, a big lookup table. Start by picking a colour at random and then select the others from there. I have to admit I don't know how to generate the lookup table, that's an exercise for you :)

Comment: @just_name - I've added a couple of links to my answer to help get you started. The table includes a Hue (as a degree value) which allows you to find the complementary colours.

Answer (score 3):

Why not create a list of colours that you think would suit each other (like the basic Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Orange etc.) and simply pick random colours off the list, safe in the knowledge that no matter what colours are picked, they will all look reasonably good together?

Comment: i don't know exactly the number of categories, they change according to specific state so that i need more general method.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the earlier answer, you could use a service such as http://www.colr.org/ (which creates colour schemes from images) to create colour schemes that are guaranteed "non-strange", then pick a random colour from that scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing on earth:

Use the HSV color model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and just change one of the parameters (Hue) to have a nice colour transitions.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to figfure out an algorithm using a colorpicker from the web and see what happens when you change the RGB-values with a fixed amount. If you can find that (for example: add 10 to the R-value and if the end is reached add 10 to the G value and reset the R-value), you can dynamicaly make a list for yourself.

Second option is that when you know you have an ultimate maximum of categories, you can create a list and use that.

Answer (score 1):

A trick I use in similar situations is to generate three random intensity values, then use these three values in six possible RGB combinations to generate a palette of colors having constant intensity and uniform contrast.

Example using three intensity values 33, 88, and aa.

```
<div style='background-color: #3388aa;'>Color 1</div>
<div style='background-color: #33aa88;'>Color 2</div>
<div style='background-color: #aa8833;'>Color 3</div>
<div style='background-color: #aa3388;'>Color 4</div>
<div style='background-color: #8833aa;'>Color 5</div>
<div style='background-color: #88aa33;'>Color 6</div>
```